Can UV Light Also Act to Heat a Metal Like IR?
I am familiar with the photoelectric effect.  For example, aluminum has a work function of between 4.1 to 4.3 eV.  So if ~295 nm UV light is shined on aluminum, some conduction electrons will absorb the UV photons and those electrons will be knocked out of the metal.
But what about UV light of higher wavelength (lower energy)?  For example, 350 nm.  These photons have too little energy to knock electrons completely out of the metal.
So I have some questions:

Will UV light of this wavelength induce intra-band transitions among the conduction electrons?  Or perhaps even inter-band transitions between the conduction band and much higher bands?

If so, will those electrons de-excite mainly through collisions, and might that, in turn, raise the temperature of the metal slightly?


Therefore, is one to conclude that UV light can heat a metal, just like IR?

Yes, there are unoccupied bands to put excited electrons into. Yes, they will relax back to the conduction band through scattering with other electrons or phonons. Yes that increases the temperature.
